# embedded spaces in a computed field don't show

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have some code in a computed field where I want to embed some spaces between two values:

```
var rtn:String =  doc.getItemValue("RefNo")[0] + "        " + doc.getItemValue("Company")[0];
```

the computed field Display Type =  text and the content type is String but the display strips out all the extra spaces. Is there a function like insertSpaces(5) that would insert 5 hard spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out insert "&#160" + "&#160" and display as HTML. fairly simple but really ackward.

Answer (score 0):

It will print them out as whitespace in HTML output. It will not be rendered.

You can add `&nbsp;` instead (5 times in your case).

An alternative way is to set `style="white-space: pre;"` (works IE8+ and other browsers)